# how to display "<?" AND "?>" tags in php

Tags: php, string, tags, escaping

How can i echo a string that contains the php tags

whenever I write this in my IDE, it just assumes they are part of the PHP code.

Comment: What IDE are you using? It sounds like it's syntax highlting may not be very advanced. Is your string in HTML block or a PHP block?

Comment: I am using phpED... it is in a javascript block but as part of a PHP document. Here is the line:

var oldString ="<? xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"+$('#hidden').html();

Comment: That is JavaScript. See my new answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your IDE has some quirk (from your question specificity I'd assume it's just a syntax highlighting glitch), then you can use partial / concatenated strings for comparison:

```
if ($compare == "<"."?") {
// or stristr()
```

This actually used to be a workaround for PHP3, which used a simpler tokenizer and didn't allow bare `?>` in string context.

Comment: The OP is doing the strings in JavaScript not PHP as originally thought. He will need to replace the period with a plus.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
echo "&lt;? ... ?&gt;";
```

Please see this web-site for a list of other "HTML Entities." http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Comment: how would i do it if i am not trying to echo the string but compare it to a string that contains <? instead of &lt;?

Comment: @IanMcCullough `if( "<? \$money ?>" == $something )` Check out this website to learn how to escape characters in PHP. [http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP [html_entities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

```
echo html_entities($text);
```

I usually use UTF-8 so I force this encoding:

```
echo html_entities($text, ENT_COMPAT, "utf-8");
```

Comment: `text.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;')` (pure JS) or `$(element).text(text)` (jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

```
var oldString ="<" + "? xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?" + ">"+$('#hidden').html();
```

Comment: I don't know who down-voted me, but I would appreciate it if you would read the OP's updated comments and undo your down-vote. He is doing this in a JavaScript block.